# Calling getName() method in one class work but in another it does not

Tags: java, arraylist, observable

I am making a program to iterate through an arraylist of objects and print them to the screen. To do this I am using a getName() method. When I call it from one of my classes, nothing is returned, but calling it from a different class works.

```
public class Customer {

    String name;

    public Customer(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }


    public String getName() {

        return this.name;
    }

}
```

The code above is the getName() method I want to call.

```
public class Store {

    private String name;
    private ArrayList<Customer> customersStore;

    public Store(String name) {
        this.name=name;
        customersStore=new ArrayList<Customer>();
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer customer) {
        customersStore.add(customer);
        for(int i  = 0; i<customersStore.size();i++){
           System.out.print(customersStore.get(i).getName() + " ");
        }
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public ArrayList<Customer> getCustomers() {
        return this.customersStore;
    }

}
```

Because the program was not printing anything off as a way of debugging I had the program print off the arraylist whenever a new value was entered and found that it worked.

```
public class StoreView implements Observer{

    public void printStoreDetails(Store store) {

        ArrayList<Customer> customerList;

        // Displaying the customer list

        customerList = store.getCustomers();

        // Displaying the values after iterating through the list
        System.out.println("\nThe Customer names are:");
        for(int i  = 0; i<customerList.size();i++){
            System.out.print(customerList.get(i).getName() + " ");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object name) {

        printStoreDetails(new Store("Sears"));
    }
}
```

However, when I try to call it from the StoreView class above, it does not print anything off. Which is what I dont understand.

The input is gathered from a scanner in the main class

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            Store myStore = new Store("Sears");
            StoreView myStoreView = new StoreView();

            StoreController myStoreController = new StoreController(myStore, myStoreView);
            Customer aCustomer;

            System.out.println("Enter customer names for store " + myStore.getName());

            myStoreController.addObserver(myStoreView);

            while(input.hasNext()) {
                aCustomer = new Customer(input.nextLine());
                myStoreController.addCustomer(aCustomer);
            }


        }
    }
```

The input is then sent to StoreController to be added to the ArrayList

```
public class StoreController extends Observable {

    private Store model;
    private StoreView view;

    public StoreController(Store model, StoreView view){
        this.model = model;
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void addCustomer(Customer name){
        model.addCustomer(name);
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers();
    }


}
```

I'm not super familiar with observers but the overall goal of the program is to update StoreView whenever customers are added to the Store through StoreController. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: as far as we know, you never added a Customer to that Store. You'll need to show all relevant code for us to understand the issue at hand

Comment: I added the remainder of the classes that show how the data is input. It is entered through a scanner and then with each new input, the arraylist is printed again with the updated entry. It is not how I would normally approach this problem but using an observer is part of the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance of `Store` when updating the observer; thus, it has an empty array of customers.
Change `notifyObservers();` to `notifyObservers(model);` and the update method to:

```
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object store) {
        if (store instanceof Store) {
            printStoreDetails((Store) store);
        }
    }
```